# Datepicker and FullCalender.io cannot run together datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datepicker, fullcalendar

I am trying to run instances of both fullcalendar and datepicker in one html file. I can get full calendar working as expected but I cannot get datepicker working along side.

When I run datepicker in its own separate html file it works fine.

The error that I get in the console is the below:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepicker is not a function TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

and

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.

I am running this through Django but I don't think that is relevant.

Below is my code to make this happen, the idea is to open the modal and have a datepicker in there:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <link href="{%  static 'css/fullcalendar.min.css' %}" rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href="{%  static 'css/fullcalendar.print.min.css' %}" rel='stylesheet' media='print' />

  <script src="{%  static 'js/moment.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{%  static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{%  static 'js/fullcalendar.min.js' %}"></script>


  <link href="{%  static 'css/datepicker.css' %}" rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src="{%  static 'js/datepicker.js' %}"></script>
  
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      theme: true,
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
      },
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views

      weekNumbers: false,
      weekNumbersWithinDays: true,
      weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',

      selectable: true,
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events

    });

  });

</script>
<style>

body {
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

#main-footer{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;

}

</style>
<title>{% block title %}ProSquad | Scheduler{% endblock %}</title>
</head>


<body id="home">

  
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">
      Launch the demo
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Datepicker</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="datepicker">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div id="calendar"></div>

      <footer id="main-footer" class="bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center text-white py-4">
              <h3>LoopLab</h3>
              <p>Copyright &copy;
                <span id="year"></span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>

      
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    //Get Current Year for copyright
    $('#year').text(new Date().getFullYear());
  </script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
        autoHide: true,
        zIndex: 2048,
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This has been driving me mad for days and hoping it's just something stupid, any help would be seriously appreciated!

Comment: did you try importing datepicker.js before fullcalendar?

Comment: I did, still get the same errors..

Comment: Why are you importing jquery slim and jquery both?

Comment: I think  slim was needed for datepicker and the other one was needed for fullcalendar, i tested with just the slim one and fullcalendar still works with this but not datepicker

Comment: " slim was needed for datepicker and the other one was needed for fullcalendar"...no, you only ever need one copy of jQuery. The slim version is just missing a few of the less essential functions like ajax. So what you're doing is basically creating two copies of (almost) the same thing. This is unlikely to produce good results. Unless you are really desperate to save a few KB of bandwidth then just use the full version and remove the slim one.